# What is the best way to CRUD dynamically created tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm creating(ed) an ASP.NET application (SQL Server backend) that allows the user (a business) to create their own tables and fields. They will all be child tables of a parent table (non-dynamic) and have proper PK/FK relationships (default fields when the table is created).

However, I don't like my current method of updating/inserting and selecting the fields. I was going to create an SP that was passed the proper keys and table names, then have it return the proper SQL statement. I'm thinking that it might make more sense to just pass the name/value pairs of fields/values and have an SP actually process them. Is this the best way to do it? If so, I'm not good at SP's so any examples of how?

Comment: Sounds like your talking about an EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) structure.  Have a look here it may help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

Comment: I had a similar requirement for a project I did a while back.  I ended up using a table with 2 columns: ID (PK) and Data where Data was XML data-type.  I then created and stored XML.

Comment: I've also written about EAV here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway.aspx EAV gets a lot of bad press but the folks against it don't understand that not all models have the ability to lock down schema. What I like about EAV over storing data in XML is that indexes (especially filtered indexes) can be customized for pain points much more easily.

Comment: @JohnHartsock thanks for the suggestion of EAV. I had never known about that model before. My guess is that I won't have too many fields, maybe 25-100 fields that customers will create. Does this still make sense if I'm not expecting them to create 1,000's? Still, how do you write code that is parameterized if I follow my original plan?

Comment: @AaronBertrand very good article. I understand how it could be used. However, same question, does it make a big difference if the expected quantity of fields is much smaller? I'm very hesitant to make such a drastic change at this juncture in the project. I'm trying to sell this as a product, so there's no guarantee that I'll make a return already. (Plus there is always v2.0 after all.)

Comment: The problem isn't about the number of columns, it's that their metadata (name, value range, data type) is unknown today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with the EAV model, but it does sound like it might be a good idea for implementing what you're trying to achieve.  However, if you already have a system in place, an overhaul could be very expensive.

If the queries you're making against the user tables are basic CRUD operations, what about just creating CRUD stored procs for each table?  E.g. -

Table:

```
acme_orders
```

Stored Procs:

```
acme_orders_insert
acme_orders_update
acme_orders_select
acme_orders_delete
... [other necessary procs]
```

I have no idea what the business needs are for these tables, but I imagine that whatever you're doing currently could be translated into doing the same thing with stored procs.

Answer (score 0):

> I was going to create an SP that was passed the proper keys and table names, then have it >return the proper SQL statement. I'm thinking that it might make more sense to just pass the >name/value pairs of fields/values and have an SP actually process them.

Assuming you mean the proc would generate and then execute the SQL (sometimes known as dynamic SQL) this can work, but it probably performs slower than static / compiled SQL, as in normal procs.